# failed to submit Leaderboard score in facebook instant games

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I am not able to submit score on leaderboard. Also, i am very new to javascript, so i dont know exactly how to catch error thrown by setScoreAsync

```
    FBInstant.getLeaderboardAsync('global')
          .then(function(leaderboard) {     
            return leaderboard.setScoreAsync(gameManager.highscore);
          })
          .then(function(entry) {
            console.log(entry.getScore()); // 42
            console.log(entry.getPlayer().getName());
          }
          });
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure 'global' leaderboard in developer dashboard (with "Make leaderboard contextual" option set to 'NO').
Use:

```
.catch(function (err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
```

for catching errors, the same way like .then()

Comment: Thanks a lot Bartek